# Firefox emulator

Tags: firefox, mobile, emulation

I don't know if this is the correct site, but do you know if there is a good emulator for mobile firefox out there? I want to make some tests on mobile firefox and I don't have a smartphone available :S

Comment: i have tried the Firefox OS simulator and it works great but the icons do not show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mozilla provides windows, linux and mac os versions of Firefox mobile: https://www.mozilla.com/en/mobile/download/

Comment: Thank you very very much...it was so easy that I hadnt thought it was an emulator but *real* firefox :)

Comment: When designing a game for the firefox os. I do not have a device yet rather just the simulator. How can a person replicate touch movement rather than mouse clicks. What about if a person had an asteroids type game and wanted to use touch screen as an option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firefox OS Simulator, too. It's a browser add-on. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-os-simulator/

Take note: When you install this add-on and encountered a pop-up related to the add-on, just press "Continue" and NOT.. I repeat NOT "Stop Script" :)